# Question about building a program from scratch

Tags: android, c, windows, macos, frontend

All my life I've build my games and programs on top of prebuilt software, Unity,Unreal, Python etc, But I've never really learned how it's standardly done in the industry, ya engines are cool, but they also cause problems such as having limitations with what you can do, as well has having to work around bugs etc. But let's look at other software: MS Office, 7Zip, Evernote, Firefox, Youtube, Amazon Alexa app, Inkscape,  Autodesk cad, Photoshop etc. These are just some random examples but they were NOT built in an engine yet manage to be cross-platform. What skills/languages are required to do that? To be clear I'm not asking for a miracle answer that can tell me everything I need to know, but I'm looking for a guide on the tools used to build things like that. Is it C++? Is it OpenGL? Am I still think too high up? I don't know much about it but are that the right direction? I've heard of things like electron but I think you could consider that more of an engine. I can't imagine these companies doing this at the binary level, I would think that would be absurd doing that for every program in such a day in age, also impossible for startups like Mozilla and Evernote to do as brand new companies without a large amount (if any) incoming revenue. In the end, I guess what I'm asking is, what is the industry standard when building cross-platform programs? What are the tools they tend to use? And what sources could I learn from to learn ore about this?

---

P.S. To be clear I understand things like Evernote, Youtube, Alexa App, etc have back-ends behind them, but I'm not talking about those, I primarily mean the front-end though I would think whatever the standard is would be capable of handling a back-end.

Answer (score 3):

Ex-Middleware Game dev here. To make anything work on *any* given platform, at the lowest level you will have to start accessing the OS or hardware specific API's (So for example, on windows, CreateFile to open a file, or open() on linux). The C/C++ standard libraries build on top of those API's to provide a somewhat generic platform on which to build cross platform apps.

Realistically though, the C++ stdlib isn't overly helpful in this regard, mainly because things such as graphics, windowing APIs, etc; they are all outside of the remit of the stdlibs. Another big issue for us game devs w/r/t the C++ stdlibs on console, is that their behaviour tends to be targetted towards the 'general case', rather than the specific platform. Take for example the cmath functions. I am not, under any circumstances, going to be calling the extremely inefficient std::sin() implementation. std::sin is great in one regard - it handles denormal numbers, correctly identifies NAN/INF, and has a well described method of reporting errors.

In the games engine world, we tend to spend a lot of time upfront baking assets so that these INFs/NANs cannot make their way into the games computations ever. So handling of that stuff at runtime is a waste of time, so we usually write our own maths approximations (We aren't landing a man on the moon, we're just throwing some polys at the screen, so we usually don't need the accuracy provided by the stdlibs).

So how would a typical cross platform game be organised? You'd probably see a directory structure somewhat akin to this:

```
game/
  platform/          //< contains all OS specific code (timers, mutexs, etc)
  vpu/               //< wrappers over the SIMD instructions on the platform
  maths/             //< fast versions of cmath + Vectors/Quats/Matrices/etc
  graphics/          //< wrappers over the core graphics APIs
  sound/             //< wrappers over the platform specific audio stuff
```

This is pretty much the 'platform' against which all other code is written against (in other words, we basically end up writing our own version of the C++ stdlib for each new platform). Whilst there is quite a lot of work involved in the above, it's usually *reasonably* straight forward to rewrite the entire code library when a new hardware platform comes along (e.g. Playstation 6, XBox 99, etc). Certainly that's less work than re-writing an entire game.

In some cases there are bits of that work that won't change (e.g. iOS and Android all use ARM CPUs, so the maths routines optimised for ARM NEON will be shared by both, as will the OpenGLES graphics routines).

With any luck, 99.99% of the games code will not need to be modified. With any luck - in many cases we aren't that lucky :(   [Although its easier now than it was ten years ago!]

All to often (especially on console), towards the start of a games development you'll target your lovely abstracted core libraries, and all will be good. As you near the end of the project, you'll probably end up with a load of #ifdef XBOX defines that exploit specific performance gains of that specific hardware (we need to meet that 60fps goal, and we don't really care how tbh). In extreme cases you may find that a given platform needs so many platform specific optimisations (in say, the renderer) that it has effectively diverged into an entirely new library for that platform only.

Anyhow. This situation is a little different on PC and android - simply because the variety of hardware is significant (unlike say an XBOX, where they are all identical!). In those cases we will be writing code against an already abstracted API (e.g. OpenGL, OpenAL, D3D, etc), and we will have to insert a lot more runtime error checking than you would on console (for example, on console we may know we have 256Mb of ram. On Android it could be 32Mb, it could be 2Gb, who knows! It doesn't matter, we need to handle failures gracefully).

When it comes to desktop APPs, for windowing APIs, the vast majority of sane people just use QT now (possibly with OpenGL if they need 3D rendering).

Comment: OK, sorry to do this to you but as a higher-up user who doesn't yet understand what's going on down below, could you dumb it down for me a bit? I got that you can do something to C++ that is generally more universal for cross-platform stuff, that's about it.